# Firebase Storage UI and Glide not showing images

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

So I have a recyclerview that loads pictures from Firebase Storage. I use the Glide library coupled with the FirebaseImageLoader to achieve this. All has been working fine until this past Monday. Images do not show anymore, there is no error, exception or something to help me out figure out why the images won't load anymore: Here are some code snippets:

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
```

ImageView I use to display images:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_promotions"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Java code that builds the Firebase storage link:

```
public StorageReference getThumbUri(String municipality){
       return Constants.STORAGE_REFERENCE.child(Constants.PROMOTIONS).child(municipality).child(promo_thumb);
        //returns e.g. gs://myfirebaseapp.com/promotions/Mahikeng/spar_thumb.png
    }
```

Code to load the image:

```
Glide.with(context).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(promotions.get(position).
                        getThumbUri(municipality)).into(holder.imageView_promotions);
```

*P.S. This code has been working fine all along, never changed anything I swear to God. All I did was update my Android Studio to 2.3.1 and update the Google support libraries to `25.3.1`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to sort it out. If there is anyone facing the same issue, revert to Firebase SDK version 10.2.1 if you recently updated it to 10.2.4, there seems to be a bug with latest SDK.

All is well

Answer (score 2):

My solution in Kotlin:

```
if (reference != null && reference.isNotEmpty()) {
            val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(reference)
            storageReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri -> Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                //.centerCrop()
                .into(mImage) }
```

reference is a string with name of file

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!